# Where i can found string:"Now listening on : http://localhost:port" at Kesterl code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel

Where i can found string:"Now listening on : http://localhost:port" at Kesterl code? This string shows when application starts.

I write simple Web Api application, hosting on kesterl and runs on Ubuntu 16.04./
So, i go to my teacher, but he want that I showed where the specified line is.

He is afraid that I brought it out by some Console.WriteLine
 and deceived him.

Tell me  where is this line in Kestrel's code or can it be somewhere else.
I understand that this is a very stupid question, but it was not I who asked it, but my instructor.

I use Asp.Net Core Web Api 2.0.

Comment: The logging framework built into asp.net core writes this to the console. Since core is open source I guess you could go find it but your teacher seems uninformed.

Comment: "He is afraid that I brought it out by some Console.WriteLine and deceived him." why doesn't he just look at your code ? I find this question highly confusing ...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-filtering

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK I bit, it's in [WebHostExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/a3300a6a605dd66d79fabc297e8d8abdb8b8edf6/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L120).  Happy Friday Y'all.